# Why is all the data getting appended to the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
paid_students=[]
for students in enrollments:
    if students['days_to_cancel']==None or students['days_to_cancel']>7:
        paid_students.append(students)
print len(paid_students)
```

Output:

```
1640
```

The value of `len(enrollments)` is also `1640`. Why are all the rows getting appended to the `paid_students` `list` even though many rows in the enrollments have `['days_to_cancel']` values having wide ranges.

Example data for enrollments

```
{u'account_key': u'448',
 u'cancel_date': u'2014-11-10',
 u'days_to_cancel': u'5',
 u'is_canceled': u'True',
 u'is_udacity': u'True',
 u'join_date': u'2014-11-05',
 u'status': u'canceled'}

{u'account_key': u'448',
 u'cancel_date': u'2015-01-27',
 u'days_to_cancel': u'0',
 u'is_canceled': u'True',
 u'is_udacity': u'True',
 u'join_date': u'2015-01-27',
 u'status': u'canceled'}
```

Source-Udacity

Comment: Is Checking with " >7 " correct in your code?

Comment: @AshKetchum yes it was asked in the question that the 'days_to_cancel' have to be greater than 7.

Comment: You are comparing *strings* to an integer. `u'' > 7` is always true in Python 2, because numbers are always ordered before other object types. Convert to the value to an integer *first*.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: i added an int() in the second parameter of if,
you were comparing stings(your dic values) with integers, which in python 2 as pointed in the comments always returns true.

```
enrollments= [{u'account_key': u'448', u'cancel_date': u'2014-11-10', u'days_to_cancel': u'5', u'is_canceled': u'True', u'is_udacity': u'True', u'join_date': u'2014-11-05', u'status': u'canceled'},
{u'account_key': u'448', u'cancel_date': u'2015-01-27', u'days_to_cancel': u'10', u'is_canceled': u'True', u'is_udacity': u'True', u'join_date': u'2015-01-27', u'status': u'canceled'}]

paid_students=[]
for students in enrollments:
    if students['days_to_cancel']==None or int(students['days_to_cancel'])>7:
        paid_students.append(students)

print len(paid_students)
```

Comment: Do explain what you changed and why. Without an explanation this is not a helpful answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters added

Comment: So *why* did you add `int()`? Why does it add all elements to `paid_students` otherwise? (Yes, I already know the answer, but future visitors won't be able to get that information from your post).

Comment: @MartijnPieters i hope my answer is complete now